# Dictionary with nested and attribute lookups?

Tags: python

I am looking for a namespace-like object that behaves like a Python evaluation context when getting and setting items, roughly equivalent to the following unsafe example:

```py
from collections import UserDict

class UnsafeNamespaceDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, var):
        return eval(var, {}, self.data)

    def __setitem__(self, var, val):
        return exec(f'{var} = val', {'val': val}, self.data)
```

You can see the intended behaviour with lookups that access nested data or attributes:

```py
>>> nd = UnsafeNamespaceDict()
>>> nd['x'] = 'abc'
>>> nd['x[1]']
'b'
>>> nd['x.count']
<built-in method count of str object>
>>> nd['x[1].count']
<built-in method count of str object>
```

Setting nonexisting items fails in the natural way:

```py
>>> nd['y.z'] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __setitem__
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Tuple splicing works:

```py
>>> nd['a, b, c'] = 'ABC'
>>> nd['c']
'C'
```

How can the example class be made safe (removing `eval` and `exec`) while still allowing at least nested lookups and attribute access?

Comment: The safe way to do this would just be to write `nd['x'][1]`, which would fail in the expected way if you cannot index `nd['x']`. What you're trying to do will reduce readability and add bugs, so it might help if you explain why the normal way of indexing cannot be used here.

Comment: @Kraigolas This data structure is supposed to hold the inputs and outputs of a user-defined pipeline, which can produce and consume arbitrary data. All I have is a string that identifies the variable, using valid Python syntax. I would rather not write a DSL just for that, hence the question.

Comment: It can't be made safe.

Comment: I don't quite remember but I think there's a way to deny the code inside `eval` and `exec` access to the builtin module (maybe by adding `'__builtin__': None` to one of the dictionaries). It doesn't make it completly safe but it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into making `eval` and `exec` safe has lead me to `ast.literal_eval`, which in turn lead me to the `ast` module more generally.

It turns out that making a safe namespace with string lookup is as simple as parsing the AST for the key in `eval` mode and then traversing it while allowing only certain nodes. I give the solution below for the minimal set of AST nodes that fulfil the requirements of the original question. There is [a repository](https://github.com/ntessore/namespacedict) for a more complete implementation.

First a couple of examples:

```py
>>> # create a new namespace
>>> ns = NamespaceDict()
>>> 
>>> # basic setting and getting
>>> ns['x'] = 'abc'
>>> ns['x']
'abc'
>>> ns['x[1]']
'b'
>>> ns['x.upper']()
'ABC'
>>> 
>>> # tuple setting and getting
>>> ns['x, y, z'] = [0], [0], [0]
>>> ns['x[0], y[0], z[0]'] = 1, 1, 1
>>> ns['x, y, z']
([1], [1], [1])
```

You get the idea. This is the implementation:

```py
import ast


class NamespaceDict:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data if data is not None else {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, str):
            raise TypeError('key is not a string')
        expr = ast.parse(key, filename='<key>', mode='eval')
        return self._get(key, expr.body)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(key, str):
            raise TypeError('key is not a string')
        expr = ast.parse(key, filename='<key>', mode='eval')
        return self._set(key, expr.body, value)

    @staticmethod
    def _bad_node(key, node):
        details = ('<key>', node.lineno, node.col_offset+1, key)
        raise SyntaxError('invalid syntax', details)

    def _get(self, key, node):
        meth = getattr(self, f'_get_{node.__class__.__name__}', None)
        if meth is None:
            self._bad_node(key, node)
        return meth(key, node)

    def _set(self, key, node, value):
        meth = getattr(self, f'_set_{node.__class__.__name__}', None)
        if meth is None:
            self._bad_node(key, node)
        return meth(key, node, value)

    def _get_Name(self, key, node):
        return self.data[node.id]

    def _set_Name(self, key, node, value):
        self.data[node.id] = value

    def _get_Num(self, key, node):
        return node.n

    def _get_Str(self, key, node):
        return node.s

    def _get_Constant(self, key, node):
        return node.value

    def _get_Subscript(self, key, node):
        return self._get(key, node.value)[self._get(key, node.slice)]

    def _set_Subscript(self, key, node, value):
        self._get(key, node.value)[self._get(key, node.slice)] = value

    def _get_Slice(self, key, node):
        lower = node.lower and self._get(key, node.lower)
        upper = node.upper and self._get(key, node.upper)
        step = node.step and self._get(key, node.step)
        return slice(lower, upper, step)

    def _get_Index(self, key, node):
        return self._get(key, node.value)

    def _get_Attribute(self, key, node):
        return getattr(self._get(key, node.value), node.attr)

    def _set_Attribute(self, key, node, value):
        setattr(self._get(key, node.value), node.attr, value)

    def _get_Tuple(self, key, node):
        return tuple(self._get(key, e) for e in node.elts)

    def _set_Tuple(self, key, node, value):
        i = iter(value)
        n = 0
        for e in node.elts:
            try:
                v = next(i)
            except StopIteration:
                raise ValueError(f'not enough values to unpack '
                                 f'(expected {len(node.elts)}, got {n})')
            self._set(key, e, v)
        try:
            next(i)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'too many values to unpack '
                             f'(expected {len(node.elts)})')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `object` class, by default it allows changes to the `class.__dict__` with the `.` operador. If you still want the `eval` like functionality you can always write your own implementation.
Note that this works on other builtins and libraries but you need to check if the changes you made conflict with the default.

```
class Name_Space(object):

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if '_even' in name:
            ret = object.__getattribute__(
                self, name.replace('_even', '')
            )
            if ret % 2:
                return False
            else:
                return True

        if '_len' in name:
            return len(object.__getattribute__(
                self, name.replace('_len', '')
            ))

        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ns = Name_Space()

    ns.num = 3
    print(ns.num_even)

    ns.a, ns.b, ns.c = 'ABC'
    print(ns.a)

    ns.text = 'ZXC'
    print(ns.text_len)
    print(ns.text.lower())

    ns.nested = Name_Space()
    ns.nested.arr = [1, 2, 3]
    print(ns.nested.arr_len)
```